# Factoring question from March $2013$ AMATYC exam

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For how many pairs of positive integers $(n, \space m)$ with $n, \space m < 100$ are both of the polynomials $x^2 + mx + n$ and $x^2 + mx - n$ factorable over the integers?

I have found four solutions:
$$x^2 + 10x + 24$$
$$x^2 + 20x + 96$$
$$x^2 + 13x + 30$$
$$x^2 + 17x + 60$$

but I found these by trial and error.

I do not see how to systematically answer this question.
Any help?

Comment: You need $m^2+4n$ and $m^2-4n$ to both be square.

Comment: The rather stupid bruteforce program here (http://ideone.com/wuyoZZ) spits all the pairs $(m,n)$. You have missed several ones, but I don't see any obvious pattern. Namely they are $$5,6$$
$$10,24$$
$$13,30$$
$$15,54$$
$$17,60$$
$$20,96$$
$$25,84$$